# Java Application (With GUI) as a service

Tags: java, user-interface, windows-services

We have a a Java app that takes a few registers off a database and sends them back and forth to a web service, nothing too complicated. This java app has a GUI that informs the user about what's going on with the operations it performs, as well as providing means for configuring certain aspects of its execution and giving the user the opportunity to deal with errors that may happen.

The thing is, this application needs to run all the time, even if the user isn't logged on. I tried setting a windows task to make it run when the computer starts, but if that happens the program runs on the background and the interface never comes up.

We could break the interface away from the main project and make them run separately, so the service runs on the background quietly and the user is free to open and close the interface to their heart's content, but unfortunately we suffer from coupling problems in our project which makes that road a little more arduous than it should be.

So the question is: Is there a way to set a service up so that it runs even when the user isn't logged in, but once he does, the interface also comes up?

Our only target platform is, for now, Windows.

Comment: How does the user log in if there is no GUI?

Comment: The user logs into the Operating System. Our application doesn't have a login/pass as it only runs on certain servers which few people have access to. The program also doesn't require login information to perform its operations. It merely probes the webservice and the database for new stuff to process and does its job.

Answer (score 3):

to your question : "Is there a way to set a service up so that it runs even when the user isn't logged in, but once he does, the interface also comes up?" the response is Yes and called JavaExe.
look its examples in JavaExe.zip, in particular example8 or 23

Comment: I took a look, and it seems there still must be a separation between the interface and service classes for it to work. Also, from the documentation, it says that it "makes it possible the Java application to have his icon in the taskbar and possibly one or two menus associated (a menu for the right click and another for the left click)."

That will not do.

Comment: why don't ? the service part can run always (if configured as AUTO) and the UI part run when the user log on.

Comment: If you read my innitial post, you'll see we are facing coupling issues between the service and application parts which makes separation between the two, although the more elegant and correct path, not an option at this time. In other words, it seems, from the documentation, that said separadion would have to be made for this strategy to work properly and we cannot afford to do that right now.

Comment: ... but anyway versions of Windows since Vista no longer allows the services directly interact with the user. So to solve your problem, you have two solutions: 1) separate the UI portion of the Service and run it as current user, as JavaExe done. 2) or use Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

Only separation of UI is an answer here. Downgrading to XP doesn't make sense. You can also simply build that as a webapp and try to leverage esbeetle.com for interfaceing and doing all the logic.